ExtJs7: How can I use tools config within a custom grouped grid header that is collapsible?
I have a grouped grid that uses custom components containing an array of tools for the group headers. If the grid is configured to have collapsible headers (which is what I want), the component's tools config is ignored. For some reason the tools are only compiled if the collapsible option is turned off.
Here is a Fiddle that illustrates the problem.
Apparently the collapsible config (Ext.dataview.ListCollapser) is overriding any internal tools config, but I haven't been able to figure out if there is an easy way to override this behavior. I want to be able to programmatically expand/collapse the group, and actually don't care for the preconfigured collapser tool button.
I have attempted a workaround by setting the tools config via the parent grid's groupHeader option, but that has quickly become messy as I want to bind tool values to custom component's viewModel.
